# How is protocol.json used when minting NFTs?

Tags: cardano-cli, nft

I'm tinkering with creating NFTs via the cardano-cli. The various "how-to" pages I have found all have me download protocol.json using

```
cardano-cli query protocol-parameters \
--testnet-magic 1097911063 \
--out-file protocol.json
```

What I do not see is how that file is then utilized. It is never accessed or referenced in any of the steps needed to create the NFT, and certainly not in any of the code. Every other piece of code has very precise file references. Can anyone shed light? Thanks.

Comment: In my understanding, their are various parameters like the constants involved when computing minimum ada requirement in a UTxO, etc., which are mentioned in `protocol.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protocol.json` file from `cardano-cli` contains protocol parameters of the current network (mainnet, preview, preprod...).

It is used by `cardano-cli` when using various subcommands, such as `cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee`.

*Actually, I do not know of any other subcommand using this file, so you are are not using it, you do not need to generate it.*

Comment: Thanks. Development is happening so quickly that "how to" pages from only 16 months ago are already out of date.